# Is there any way to use 2 different color for the same bar in a chart?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a horizontalBar chart, made by chart.js and i have to add one more color to the bars. Like if the chart's value is more that 150, i should color the bar above (only above) 150 to red. So it's color is grey from 1-149 and red from 150-end.

[image]

I add the names and values from a mysql database. My script so far:

```
<script>
      let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

      //Global options
      Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato',
      Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
      Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#666';

      let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'horizontalBar',
        //bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
        data:{
            labels:[
                <?php

                for ($i=0; $i < count($phoneNumberArr); $i++) {
                  if ($i == count($phoneNumberArr) - 1) {
                    echo "'$phoneNumberArr[$i]'";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    echo "'$phoneNumberArr[$i]',";
                  }
                }
                 ?>
             ],
            datasets:[{
            label:'Belföldi perc',

            data:[

              <?php

                for ($i=0; $i < count($valueArr); $i++) {
                  if ($i == count($valueArr) - 1)
                  {
                    echo "'$valueArr[$i]'";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    echo "'$valueArr[$i]',";
                  }
                }


               ?>

            ],

            backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor: '#777',
            hoverBorderWidth: 3,
            hoverBorderColor: '#FFF'
          }],

        },
        options:{
          title:{
            display: false,
            text:'Összesítő',
            fontSize:25
          },
          legend:{
            display:true,
            position:'right',
            labels:{
              fontColor:'#000'
            }
          },
          layout:{
            padding:{
              left:50,
              right:0,
              bottom:0,
              top:0
            }
          },
        }
      });
    </script>
```

It should look like this

[image]

Comment: I think you should look at the stacked bar graph. You may need to put a hard fix on a number and if the number is above 150 for example, substract 150 from it and move the remain to a second dataset. Color that red and voila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved it before is by using a stacked bar in chart js. You should go through your values and every time a value is higher then 150 you set 150 in dataset1 and the amount that is above 150 you put in dataset2. and If your amount is lower than 150 you put in the amount in dataset1 and put 0 in dataset2. Here you can see an example of how I did it.

```js
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [150, 150, 60, 50, 40],
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [45,25,0,0,0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with this [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXLOPp?editors=0010):

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
const data = [150, 150, 60, 50, 40, 152, 300];

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        fill: 'origin',
      label: "My First dataset",
            borderColor: 'black',
      data: data,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    }
  },
   plugins: [{
        beforeRender: function (x, options) {
                var c = x.chart;
            var dataset = x.data.datasets[0];
            var xScale = x.scales['x-axis-0'];
            var xPos = xScale.getPixelForValue(0);
            console.log(c)
            var gradientFill = c.ctx.createLinearGradient(c.width, 0, 133.3333333333335, 0);
            gradientFill.addColorStop(0, 'red');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(xPos / c.height - 0.01, 'red');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(xPos / c.height + 0.01, 'black');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(1, 'black');
            console.log(x.data.datasets[0])
            for (var i = 0; i < x.data.datasets[0]._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data.length; i++ ) {
              var model = x.data.datasets[0]._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
              model.backgroundColor = gradientFill;
            }
        }
    }]
})
```